# Does Apple Pay store shipping address?

Tags: ios, ios8, applepay

Does Apple Pay store the shipping address? Apple's own documentation gives confusing/conflicting information.

In Apple's [UX guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/ux-guidelines/), it says:

> After the user authorizes the purchase, Apple Pay responds by providing the billing and shipping addresses (if needed), along with the payment information.

But in [`PKPaymentRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPaymentRequest_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/PKPaymentRequest) documentation, under `shipppingAddress` property, it says:

> If you already have a shipping address on file, set it here. The user can either use the address you specify or select a different address.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is contradictory; In the later case, you are setting what is presented to the user (which they might alter), in the former case you are getting back what the user actually entered.

Comment: For those voting to close as off topic, they are asking about the programmatic implications for applications using Apple Pay and its API. That seems on topic to me.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't conflicting information. You're looking at two different parts of the process. In the first part, you're requesting that the user makes a payment. This is where you specify the cost, information required, and information you already have available. If you set the `shippingAddress` property, then Apple can give the user a choice between your address, or specifying a different one. Setting this property is not required, however, and Apple will collect and provide a shipping address to you if you request it. It is simply a convenience for users.

Once your payment is authorized, then Apple Pay will respond with the shipping address if requested. This address may be the one you provided earlier, but it could also be a different address specified during the checkout procedure.